# Savon::UnknownOptionError: convert_dashes_to_underscores

Tags: savon

I am using Savon 2.11.1 as a Ruby SOAP client. 
Savon uses Nori to translate the SOAP response XML to a Hash. Nori supports the option convert_dashes_to_underscores which by default converts all dashes in SOAP response to underscores. 
I tried to use this option in the client's constructor but I got the following error message

Savon::UnknownOptionError: Unknown global option: :convert_dashes_to_underscores.

Why is this option not supported for Savon? Any workaround?

Thanks
M

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it isn't supported. I guess because nobody needed it up until now. I propose you extend the code, create the unit tests, upload the sources to github and send a pull request to the main project. Simple as that.

You can also look into the documentation  where you'll find that the following symbols are available to control conversion

```
:camelcase
:lower_camelcase
:upcase
:none
```

http://savonrb.com/version2/globals.html